# Не отображаются иконки приложения из примера

Tags: c++, windows, qt, иконки

Разбираю [пример](http://doc.crossplatform.ru/qt/4.7.x/demos-textedit.html) из документации Qt. Возникла проблема с отображением иконок на Windows. Ошибок не выдает, но иконок нет. Вот скриншот.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Иконки для MAC мне не нужны поэтому их я качать не стал. Единственное что изменил, путь к картинкам. У меня они лежат в папке `images`, а не в папке `images/win`, как в примере, но все необходимые изминения в код я внес.

Вот файл ресурсов

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC>
<RCC version="1.0">
<qresource prefix="/">
<file>images/logo32.png</file>
<file>images/editcopy.png</file>
<file>images/editcut.png</file>
<file>images/editpaste.png</file>
<file>images/editredo.png</file>
<file>images/editundo.png</file>
<file>images/exportpdf.png</file>
<file>images/filenew.png</file>
<file>images/fileopen.png</file>
<file>images/fileprint.png</file>
<file>images/filesave.png</file>
<file>images/textbold.png</file>
<file>images/textcenter.png</file>
<file>images/textitalic.png</file>
<file>images/textjustify.png</file>
<file>images/textleft.png</file>
<file>images/textright.png</file>
<file>images/textunder.png</file>
<file>images/zoomin.png</file>
<file>images/zoomout.png</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

Строка с путем к картинкам

```
const QString rsrcPath = ":/images";
```

Папка с картинками

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Pro-файл абсолютно такой же как в примере.

```
TEMPLATE        = app


CONFIG          += qt warn_on

HEADERS         = textedit.h
SOURCES         = textedit.cpp \
               main.cpp
RESOURCES += textedit.grc

build_all:!build_pass {
   CONFIG -= build_all
   CONFIG += release
}

# install
target.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_DEMOS]/textedit
sources.files = $$SOURCES $$HEADERS $$RESOURCES *.pro *.html *.doc images
sources.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_DEMOS]/textedit
INSTALLS += target sources

 OTHER_FILES += \
 textedit.grc
```

Больше ничего не менял, но иконки не отображаются. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Не пытайтесь просто копипастить код.  Пробуйте писать сами и пытаться разобраться что не так. Вам в консоли отладчика должно было выдать сообщение что у вас не открылся файл с ресурсами

Comment: @jNX Странно, теперь, когда я скопировал pro-файл проекта еще раз, при сборке пишет, что файл ресурсов не найден.

Comment: @jNX Мне все равно нужно будет изменить этот код, я просто смотрю как реализованы некоторые кнопки. Хочу сначала воспользоваться программой, посмотреть, как все работает, но словил такой неприятный баг.

Comment: дал же ответ ниже

Comment: это не баг , добавьте скриншот директории с исходными файлами

Comment: Формат не просто так придуман , у вас grc файл а нужно qrc - Qt Resource System

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Файл должен быть .qrc**
2. Прикрепите свой .pro файл
3. В pro файл необходимо добавить

   RESOURCES     = resources.qrc